# Cuenta gris de facebook se elimina y es propietaria de una página

Tags: facebook

Nos ha llegado un aviso de que nuestra cuenta gris de facebook se va a eliminar, esa cuenta es la propietaria de una página.

Si se borra, ¿se borra también la página?

No me deja cambiar el propietario, solo asignar administradores. ¿Si esa pagina tiene otra cuenta como administrador se conservara y los propietarios pasaran a ser los otros administradores?

Comment: tengo el mismo problema de cuenta gris y que administra una página, pero ésta sólo tiene como administrador la cuenta gris. ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar? No puedo perder la página de empresa. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Al eliminar la cuenta, la página seguirá existiendo, no se eliminará.
Solo ya no habrá propietario, en efecto los rangos mas altos serán los administradores.

Comment: Se te agradece el apoyo, pero preguntas como esta no se ajustan a [ask] y por ende es muy seguro terminen cerradas, como consejo evitemos responderlas